# which node will execute events in master-master setup

Tags: mariadb, galera

Am newbie in this database replication. Right now on server master-master setup with Galera setup.

If I have events running in the database. It means from which master its running.
If one master down then the second master will execute that events or for that something can be done in the configuration.

Anyone like to suggest something related to it ?

```
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 4123677
Server version: 10.1.39-MariaDB-1~stretch mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab, and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(test)]>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [events](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/events/) in a MariaDB Galera Cluster must be configured to run on only one of the nodes. While `CREATE EVENT` is replicated to the other nodes, you have to choose which node to use for running the event scheduler: Execute `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` on the node where you want events to run, or set it in your config file if you want it the setting to survive a restart.

If that node is down, then there is no automatic failover for events, so if you'd like to run the events on another node, you'll have to enable the event scheduler on that node.

You could perhaps control the `event_scheduler` setting through software: a script could poll each node, and make sure the setting is enabled on one and only one node.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, It means that if I set event_schedular=ON on all nodes then also it will not run when primary server goes fail ?

Comment: @AnkitDoshi My understanding is that if you have `event_scheduler=ON` on all the nodes, then the events will also run on each and every node - which means that the effect of the events such as DML write statements (INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE ...) will be replicated to the other nodes, so in effect you will be executing each event several times. But if that is OK in your use-case, then this will protect events against loss of a node, yes.

Comment: It mean, that if one node down then another node execute that event and go ahead right ?

Comment: Here, I have one concern Is it possible to get any information like which node execute that event that can i get with use of any variable ?

Comment: @AnkitDoshi 1) Yes, that's right. 2) Yes, you can use a variable like `@@hostname`.